# Why is my t-test intuition so far from reality?

Tags: normal-distribution, t-test, standard-error

Interpretation of t-test value (2 tailed): ~20% chance that these results could have been obtained randomly.

My intuition: MEAN_2 - MEAN_1 = ~3% of MIN(STD_1, STD2). Calculate area under normal normal PDF between -3% and +3% of std from mean which is ~2.5%.

Why is the t-test result so far off from my intuition???

---

COUNT_1 = 3572

MEAN_1 = 702

STD_1 = 2926

---

COUNT_2 = 4596

MEAN_2 = 621

STD_2 = 2730

---

t = 1.26

df = 7403

Comment: You are not computing a t-test, because you have used the standard deviations of the data in place of the standard *errors*.

Answer (score 5):

The test statistic in the ordinary two sample t-test is a difference in means divided by the standard deviation of that difference in means (the standard deviation of the distribution of some statistic, such as a difference in means is called a *standard error*).

The standard error of the difference in means decreases as the sample sizes increase (because the individual sample means become more precise).

You seem to be using (as @whuber suggests) the standard deviations of the samples to obtain the intuition of 'how different' the samples are. This ignores the fact that sample means have smaller standard deviations than the samples from which they're computed.

For example, if I have 100 observations with mean 40 and standard deviation 15, then the standard error of their mean is *one tenth* as large as the standard deviation of the data.

If the sample sizes were only 4, the standard error of the means would be half as large as the standard deviations of the data - five times as big as when the sample sizes were 100.

Comment: Can you help me understand this?  According to the wikipedia page, to calculte t, you are using s^2, which the article says it the unbiased estimator of variance.  Where does standard error fit into this?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student's_t-test#Unequal_.28or_equal.29_sample_sizes.2C_unequal_variances

Comment: According to the part you pointed to, you compute this: $s_{\overline{X}_1 - \overline{X}_2} = \sqrt{{s_1^2 \over n_1} + {s_2^2  \over n_2}}$. See how the $s^2$ terms are divided by those corresponding $n$'s? The square of the LHS is the variance of the difference in sample means. The two $s^2/n$ terms on the RHS are squares of standard errors of means. They are calculated from standard deviations of samples but they are different from those standard deviations (they're typically much smaller)

Comment: s = standard deviations of samples?  Did I get that right?  How is this calculated then?  Sorry I'm not very smart.  Thanks.

Comment: Yes, both the $s$ terms are standard deviations from the samples. To get the standard deviation of sample means, you divide $s$ by $\sqrt{n}$, where $n$ is the number of values in that sample.

Comment: See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_error#Standard_error_of_the_mean); this stuff would normally be taught before any t-tests.